# Repeat background in impactjs

Tags: javascript, mobile

I wan to create a game that has a repeating background in y-axis like this:

[image]

I have ticked the "repeat" in weltmeister and the background is repeated.  But in the game run, the background is only repeated once the background run finish.  So, now I will have a blank background in between the background run finish and the new background come out.

Any idea to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Ensure you have increased the Distance property for the background layer from 1 to 2 within Weltmeister. Also ensure your level is being saved properly and permissions have been applied to the `lib/game/levels` folder.

```
chmod -R 777 lib/game/levels
```

Comment: @miniram: Did you manage to fix the background issue you were having?

Comment: yes, actually i found out that I have preload the background image and made it not able to repeat itself. Thank you very much

Comment: @miniram Glad you have it all sorted out. There are some active members over IRC that can help you with issues as well. Cheers.